# deep learning - how to train silhouette image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, tensorflow, image-recognition

[image]

I want to train silhouette images to figure out the original image

I'm planning to use Tensorflow.

Once I've thought about using Automatic colorization, but I have no idea if it works well since what it only has is just an outline of the image.

Is there any way to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: The problem is very loosely constrained. For instance in your example, he could be wearing a different T-Shirt (or a variety of other clothing), and lighting could be from any angle, and it would still be valid result. So I would expect output from a predictor to be either vague or highly variable or both. I'm not aware of any attempts to solve this problem, so cannot answer properly. I'd guess some extension of a generative model like a GAN or VAE where you could add the silhouette as a constraint might work.

Comment: There is some work in this general area, you might be taking it to a logical extreme, but this might be a nice read to get ideas flowing: http://www.foldl.me/2015/conditional-gans-face-generation/